# If $G(H) = \{ g \in G : ghg^{-1} \in H \text{ for all } h \in H \}$ and $G = \mathbb{Z} $, $H = 3 \mathbb{Z} $, what is $G(H)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following problem:

Let the group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of the group $G$. We define $G(H) = \{ g \in G : ghg^{-1} \in H \text{ for all } h \in H \}$. Then if $G = \mathbb{Z} $ and $H = 3 \mathbb{Z} $, what is $G(H)$?

I don't know how to understand this problem. I get that the problem relates to normal subgroups but I don't get how $G$ and $H$ operate together to form $G(H)$. Any help given is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the symbols $G$ and $H$ by $\mathbb Z$ and $3\mathbb Z$ in $\{ g \in G : ghg^{-1} \in H \text{ for all } h \in H \}$?

Comment: @GitGud yes, but I didn't know if I was doing things correctly. I got that $G(H)$ was just $3 \mathbb{Z}$ but I don't feel confident about it. I saw a result of an example similar to this one but with $2 \mathbb{Z}$ and $G(H)$ ended un being $\{ 0, 1 \}$, with my problem it would be $\{ 0, 1 , 2 \}$ but I still don't get how it makes sense.

Comment: I suggest you include your working in getting $G(H) = 3\mathbb Z$, I think it will be of great help in nudging you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. what I did was $ghg^{-1}$ is $\{ \mathbb{Z} + 3\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}^{-1} \}$ with addition $g^{-1}$ is just the negative of $g$ so $ghg^{-1} = g + h + (-g) = h$ and since $h \in  3\mathbb{Z} $ then $G(H) = 3\mathbb{Z} $

Comment: Here's a question that will help understand your knowledge of something related to your try. If $A = \{0, 3, 5\}$, what is $\left\{x \in A\colon 5 = 5\right\}$?

Comment: I think your example helped me a lot. What we're doing is seeing all elements of the form $ghg^{-1}$ as $h$ varies over $H$, $G(H)$ is just another way of expressing that we want to check if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, indeed it is so $G$ suffers no change. Then $G(H) =  \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Nice $\ddot \smile$ I suggest you answer the question yourself below, a clean, to the point answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb{Z} $ is abelian, the condition $ghg^{-1}\in H$ say nothing. Then, $G(H) = G=\mathbb{Z} $.